# Windows not booting after boot repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on acer predator desktop on diffrent partition and it was booting to Windows only. So i've read that my motherboard has hard-coded efi file to boot from so I ran boot-repair on live Linux and checked the box for fixing hard coded efi file. After that I saw the grub with options to boot to Ubuntu or windows boot manager but when I chose windows it returns to grub, Ubuntu works fine
How do I fix the windows boot manager?

Comment: Can you boot Windows directly from Acer's UEFI boot menu, not thru grub? Grub only boots working Windows. Or Windows fast startup, bitlocker must be off and no need for chkdsk. If you want those you can always boot from UEFI menu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I cant boot to Windows choosing Windows boot manager in uefi boot menu boots to grub

Comment: Then that is a Windows issue not related to Ubuntu. UEFI usually is set to try one boot option, it that does not work then second in UEFI boot list. You probably then need Windows repairs. Try asking on SuperUser or a Windows forum. Make sure you have good backups before any Windows repairs.